# Set PgSQL runtime-paramter from function parameter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I created a pl/pgsql function with a varchar parameter. Within this function I tried to set a runtime paramter to the value of the function parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_function (param VARCHAR)
RETURNS VOID AS $tf$
BEGIN
SET choice.p = param;
RAISE NOTICE '%', current_setting('choice.p');
END; $tf$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, the value printed is 'param'. param is treated like a string instead of a parameter name. Why is it like this, and how can I achieve what i try to do?

Comment: Are you aware that there is already a function for doing that? [set_config()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET)

Comment: No, I was not aware. It's working now! I changed the line to `PERFORM set_config('choice.p', param, false);` However, I still do not really understand what happened before.

Comment: The `SET` syntax allows unquoted values (e.g. `SET fsync = on`), and it looks like this is how it's interpreting your `param`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PL/pgSQL variables is working only for `SELECT` and DML commands. These statements has a execution plan, that can be executed with parameters. PLpgSQL runtime is able to use plpgsql variables as parameters. The static SQL commands without a plan like DDL, `SET`, `SHOW`, .. cannot to use a plpgsql variables. There is not unique way how to do it - and there is risk of ambiguous semantic. You should to use dynamic SQL in this case.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SET choice.p = %L', 'some text);
  RAISE NOTICE '%', current_setting('choice.p');
END;
$$;
```

The main reason why your example doesn't work is simple - SQL `SET` command doesn't support a expressions, and then there is not a correct way, how to apply plpgsql variables there.